# stringstream operator<< doesn't work as expected with bitwise negation

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to use a bitwise negation for a data which is stored in stringstream object. The following code works fine:

```
std::uint8_t x = 0x01;
x = ~x;

std::stringstream buf;
buf << x;
std::string data = buf.str();
std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(data[0]) << std::endl;
//result: fffffffe
```

When I use bitwise negation this way:

```
std::uint8_t x = 0x01;

std::stringstream buf;
buf << ~x;
std::string data = buf.str();
std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(data[0]) << std::endl;
//result: 0x2d
```

I get an unexpected result. How to explain that ? How to use bitwise negation with operator << ?

Comment: Are you sure you're showing us the correct output for your first example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of `~x` is not of type `std::uint8_t`. You can use

```
std::uint8_t x = 0x01;

std::stringstream buf;
buf << static_cast<std::uint8_t>(~x);
std::string data = buf.str();
std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(data[0]) << std::endl;
//result: 0x2d
```

The result of `~x` is `-2`. Therefor `data[0]` is character `-` with ASCII code  `45 = 0x2d`. Instead after

```
x = ~x;
```

`x` contains the value `þ` which has ASCII value `254 = 0xfe`.

Comment: It would be even better if you mention why non-`std::uint8_t` type causes truncation.